# How do I migrate my photo library from Lightroom 1.0 into Aperture 2?

Tags: mac, migration, aperture, adobe-lightroom

I've got thousands of photos in an existing Lightroom 1.0 library and I want to move them to Aperture 2. Is there a way to do this while preserving the keyword tags and existing adjustments? Using a third party software to accomplish this is also an opton.

**P.S.** *I've haven't purchased Aperture yet, as the answer to this questions would help me decide whether it's worth the hassle. Thanks.*

Answer (score 2):

Notes at this Apple discussion thread might be useful.
[**Import from Lightroom to Aperture 2.0**](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=1390855)

Answer (score 2):

Lightroom uses [SQLite](http://sqlite.org/), an open source SQL database engine, for its library storage. However, the database schema are not documented publicly.

In principle, the use of an open source database should mean that other developers would be able to write tools that extraction information and report on the content of the library. In practice, the absence of documentation has meant that very little of that has happened.

LR does have a feature that causes the data for each image to be written to an [XMP](http://www.adobe.com/products/xmp/) data packet for each image. If the image file is in a format that Adobe knows they can safely modify, the XMP data is written into the image file itself. If the image is not (a proprietary RAW file, for instance) then the XMP data is written to a sidecar file. XMP is a dialect of XML based on RDF and inspired by the [IPTC Information Interchange Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPTC_Information_Interchange_Model) and the [Dublin Core Metadata Initiative](http://dublincore.org/).

Given that collection of XMP data, which is in a (mostly) documented format, it is likely to be possible to transform it to be easily imported into Aperture or another asset management system.